# Codeigniter - Using codeigniter email library, how do i send the email to a database list?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, email

So when using codeigniters email class i realise that sending to a single email is;

```
    $this->email->to('email1@email.com');
```

and to multiple emails is an array like below;

```
    this->email->to('one@example.com, two@example.com, three@example.com');
```

But how do i send an email to a list of contacts stored in a database, say.. 'contacts' table 'email' field.. is this possible? and if so how do i set it u-? do i use a model etc etc? im new to codeingiter so apoligies if this is simple

Comment: Don't send one email to a long list of recipients -- each recipient will be able to see all the other recipients. Instead, loop over each contact and send a separate email to each recipient. Or better, use a service 
 (ConstantContact, MailChimp, MailGun, etc.) that will track bounces for you.

Comment: for the purpose of this project, that is no issue, however i did think of using mailgun, but if i am able to find a solution in this instance then there is no need for mailgun @AlexHowansky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no native mapping of db table to email, so you have to first select, then retrieve then send

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT emailAddress from table"); //select email addresses
$sendTo=array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) //loop to build array
{
    $sendTo[]=$row->emailAddress; //add to array
}

$this->email->to($sendTo);//send email
```

Of course I have had to guess you tables email field. The other(better?) option would be to put the send in to the loop, so you send to each email address separately.

Comment: amazing, thankyou, so just to confirm, top query in my model, foreach loop in my controller, then the email->to in my email class library

Comment: well you could do it all in one place, depends on your programming 'principles'. There is more ways to structure code than grains of sand on mars.

Comment: when i try this, i get undefined variable of $sendTo :/

Comment: @Jim123 $sendTo is defined before the loop, then populated in the loop .. if your dong that in the controller then using it else where  you need make sure its in the right scope. But really i can only guess at the issue here out seeing all the code, relationships etc.

Comment: using `$this->sendTo` instead of `$sendTo` may work for you but its impossible to know currently