# Codeigniter Error when sending email to database records

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send an email to multiple contacts in my database list from an input form, it works when i hard code a specific email address, but when i try to refer to my database, i get the error:

**Message: mail(): SMTP server response: 503 5.0.0 Need RCPT (recipient)
Filename: libraries/Email.php**

I also get another error, which i think may be just my email configuration in general and i am unsure of it to;

**Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.**

MY Controller:

```
public function sendmail() {
$this->load->library('email');
$this->load->model('Email_model');
$this->load->library('session');

$this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));

$sendTo['email'] = $this->Email_model->emailsend();

$this->email->to($sendTo);
$this->email->subject('Hello This is an email');

$this->email->message($this->input->post('message'));



if ($this->email->send()){
$this->session->set_flashdata('success','Email has been sent');
redirect('dashboard');
}else{


echo $this->email->print_debugger();

}
```

My Model

```
class Email_model extends CI_Model {


public function emailsend() {

  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email from contacts");
  $sendTo=array();
  foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
  {
      $sendTo['email']=$row->email; 
  }
```

My View

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('/Dashboard/sendmail');?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<?php echo form_open('/Dashboard/sendmail');?>

  <label for="name">Your Name</label><input id="name" type="text" name="name">

  <label for="email">Your Email</label><input id="email" type="text" name="email">

  <label for="message">Your Message</label>
  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="8" cols="50"></textarea>

  <input id-"submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<p><?php echo $flash;?></p>
```

Any help for either errpr will be massively appreciated

Comment: check this answer of your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49266032/2275490

Comment: Your model's `emailsend()` function appears truncated. Does it actually return an email address after filling the `$sendTo` array?

Comment: @rickdenhaan yes it does, have multiple emails in database... and Vickel these are errors that arent mentioned in previous question..

Comment: @rickdenhaan when i var_dump the results i get the correct returns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CodeIgniter's email module expects [an array of email addresses](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#CI_Email::to) in the `to()` function. Your model's `emailsend()` function adds an `email` index to that array that isn't expected. Also, you're overwriting that `email` index's value on every iteration of the `foreach` loop, meaning your array will only ever contain the last address from your database.

It also looks like your function doesn't actually return the array after filling it, but it could be that this part is simply truncated in your question.

```
public function emailsend() {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email from contacts");
    $sendTo=array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
    {
        $sendTo[] = $row->email;
        //     ^^ remove the 'email' index
    }

    return $sendTo; // <-- add this line if you don't have it
}
```

Then, from your controller, you don't need to store the result in a separate variable unless you want to perform some additional logic on it. You can simply do this:

```
$this->email->from($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('name'));
$this->email->to($this->Email_model->emailsend());
$this->email->subject('Hello This is an email');
```

Comment: you are right, this has removed all errors, but yes this code sends it to the last email in the database, how do i avoid that?

Comment: @Jim123 Did you leave the brackets at `$sendTo[] = $row->email;`?

Comment: this is how i have it ; foreach ($query->result() as $row) //loop to build array
  {
      $sendTo[]=$row->email; //add to array

  }
return $sendTo;

Comment: That should work then. If you `var_dump($sendTo)` right before that `return`, how many addresses does it contain? And how many addresses are in your `contacts` table?

Comment: damn! took to long to write the answer :(

Comment: @rickdenhaan my bad lol, that is working, 3 of my personal emails and 2 were going to junk mail lol.. amazing work thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
public function emailsend() {
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT email from contacts");
   $sendTo=array();
   foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
   {
      //u are not changing the key
      $sendTo['email']=$row->email; 
   }
   //iguess u are returning 
   return $sendTo;
```

}

i mean a var dump on that array would be always one value, because u are reasigning the value always, then one email would be returned.

I suggest to build the array like this

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
   {

      $sendTo[]=$row->email;        
   }
```

then the vardump will look like this

```
array(11) {
 [0]=>
 string(15) "email0@mail.com"
 [1]=>
 string(15) "email1@mail.com"
 [2]=>
 string(15) "email2@mail.com"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "email3@mail.com"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "email4@mail.com"
  [5]=>
  string(15) "email5@mail.com"
  [6]=>
  string(15) "email6@mail.com"
  [7]=>
  string(15) "email7@mail.com"
  [8]=>
  string(15) "email8@mail.com"
  [9]=>
  string(15) "email9@mail.com"
  [10]=>
  string(16) "email10@mail.com"
}
```